# Updating of characer's embedding inside an RNN during character generation task

Tags: natural-language, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, generative-models

In one of the [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) of tensorflow, there is a "text generation with an RNN" tutorial.

When creating the model, they create a mapping of characters to IDs and vice versa.

Then in the model, they consider an embedding for each ID (each character).

Shouldn't that embedding also get updated during training? So it somehow can capture the relationships among characters? As far as I understood from the code, no updated embedding is returned and they always use the initial embedding.

Is my understanding right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedding matrix is a trainable parameter just like all the other parameters as you can see in the parameter listing. They get updated jointly with the rest of the model paramters.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        multiple                  17152     
_________________________________________________________________
gru (GRU)                    multiple                  3938304   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                multiple                  68675     
=================================================================
Total params: 4,024,131
Trainable params: 4,024,131
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood now.